# How do I Repeat code if condition is true

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
from typing import Text
import tweepy
import random

from tweepy import Response, tweet
client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key="XXXXXX",
    consumer_secret="XXXXXX",
    access_token="XXXXXX",
    access_token_secret="XXXXXX"
)

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import webbrowser

while True:
    url = requests.get("https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "html.parser")
    title = soup.find(class_="firstHeading").text
    printed = print(title)
    break
try:
   client.create_tweet(text="לשטח את " + title)
   print("וואלה יופי הצלחת יא בתול")
   print("יא קינג יא אלוף אין עליך יא גאון מחשבים")
except tweepy.errors.TweepyException as e:
   print("שגיאה על הראש שלך")
   print("יא אפס")
```

I would like to use this condition: `if 'משתמש' in title:` and retry the code if the condition is true, so it try and print another title, untill the condition is not true.

Comment: `while 'משתמש' in title`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep posting/Tweeting until the criterion is not met, adjust the indentation:

```
title = 'משתמש'
while 'משתמש' in title:
    # retrieve random Wikipedia page
    url = requests.get("https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "html.parser")
    title = soup.find(class_="firstHeading").text
    print(title)
    if 'משתמש' not in title:
        break

    # proceed to Tweet    
    try:
        client.create_tweet(text="לשטח את " + title)
        print("וואלה יופי הצלחת יא בתול")
         print("יא קינג יא אלוף אין עליך יא גאון מחשבים")
    except tweepy.errors.TweepyException:
        print("שגיאה על הראש שלך")
```

(The `print` statements in the try-catch block are all idented identically.)
You could also consider:

- moving all the `import` statements to the top of the file
- soft-coding the string `משתמש`, as a global constant
- splitting out into two separate functions the retrieval of the title from Wikipedia and the Tweeting, so that the while-loop only has the calls to the two functions

Comment: why did you put 'משתמש' as title in the first line?

Comment: The next line is a `while` statement that checks title,which is normally preferable to `while True`. `title` needs to be assigned before the `while` statement so as to enter the loop for a first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a while loop to try and get a url, but in the end of your code block you always break out of your loop. Even if you didn't get a response.

So add your (already provided) condition before your break, like this:

```
while True:
    url = requests.get("https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "html.parser")
    title = soup.find(class_="firstHeading").text
    printed = print(title)
    if 'משתמש' in title:
        break
```

Also, you shouldn't assign a variable to a print statement, it will just return None, so change that line to:

```
print(title)
```

instead of:

```
printed = print(title)
```

Edit:

It is convention to put your imports at the top of your code, so it might be a good idea to move:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import webbrowser
```

to the top of your file.

To prevent an infinite loop you could also put the code in a for-loop instead:

```
for _ in range(10):
    url = 
    requests.get("https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "html.parser")
    title = soup.find(class_="firstHeading").text
    if 'משתמש' in title:
         break
```

after 10 times it will stop or if the condition is True.

Comment: 1. the break does not stop the code from creating a tweet, it just limits it to one tweet instead of creating multiple tweets at once                                                                                                2. how will it know to repeat if it's true? Doesn't it just stop?

Comment: It will always have only one tweet, since to try statement is not inside of the while loop. Or am I missing something?